# Getting a list of filenames using Glob

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a list of filenames in node and I'm getting what I think is a scoping issue.

```
var files = []; 

glob(options.JSX_DEST + "/*.js", function (er, files) {
    files = files.map(function(match) {
        return path.relative(options.JSX_DEST, match);
    }); 
});
```

Since I declare files outside the call to glob, should it get populated with the results of the map function?

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the variable.

```
var globalFiles = []; 

glob(options.JSX_DEST + "/*.js", function (er, files) {
    globalFiles = files.map(function(match) {
        return path.relative(options.JSX_DEST, match);
    }); 
});
```